# Rendering depth buffer to texture using BGL fails on FBO drawing

Tags: python, opengl

I am writing a custom render engine for a level editor addon with GPU / bgl modules. I need to render a depth buffer to texture to later use in my shaders. I tried the way it is usually done with OpenGL. However, my code is failing at glCheckError('draw') after drawing the FBO with error code "invalid framebuffer operation". Are there any alternative ways to achieve a similar effect or perhaps someone could give me an idea of what is wrong with the current approach?

```
def _get_depthbuffer_texture(self):

    width, height = self.draw_obj.drawing_mgr.region.width, self.draw_obj.drawing_mgr.region.height

    texture_id_buf = Buffer(GL_INT, 1)
    fbo = Buffer(GL_INT, 1)

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
    glGenTextures(1, texture_id_buf)

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id_buf.to_list()[0])

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL)

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0)

    glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo.to_list()[0])

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, texture_id_buf.to_list()[0], 0)

    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)

    glCheckError('draw')

    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)

    fbo_status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)
    if fbo_status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        raise Exception("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE failed, CANNOT use FBO\n")

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo.to_list()[0])

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColorMask(False, False, False, False)
    glCullFace(GL_BACK)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id_buf.to_list()[0])
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    glColorMask(True, True, True, True)

    return texture_id_buf.to_list()[0]
```